# AVCapturePhotoOutput - changes in Xcode 9 Beta 5

Tags: swift, xcode, video, avkit

Just installed the latest XCode version which provided some changes in AVCapturePhotoOutput class, I wonder how to fetch the list of support flash modes. In the previous version, I used `supportedFlashModes` property which is no more available

```
open var __supportedFlashModes: [NSNumber] { get }
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess new Swiftified `supportedFlashModes` property is planned but not yet completed in beta 5.

```
open var supportedFlashModes: [AVCaptureDevice.FlashMode] { get }
```

Until the day my guess will be confirmed (can be negative), you can use `__supportedFlashModes`. It's not removed, just renamed.

(Some betas contain this sort of under-construction renaming.)

You should better send a bug report to keep Apple aware of this issue.

---

**EDIT**
Seems iOS 11 SDK/Xcode 9.1 has fixed this issue and the Release Notes of Xcode 9.1 beta say:

> - The following AVFoundation API are now available:
>
>   - `AVCaptureDevice.Format.supportedColorSpaces`
>   - `AVCaptureDevice.supportedFlashModes`
>   - `AVCapturePhotoOutput.availablePhotoPixelFormatTypes`
>   - `AVCapturePhotoOutput.availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes`
>   - `AVCapturePhotoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes`
>
> Code which was previously modified to use a double underscore as a
>   workaround should be modified to use these public symbols or **the app
>   may be rejected by the App Store**.

(Bold style added.)

Comment: @AshleyMills, unfortunately true. And I cannot find any Swiftified alternatives for such `__`-leaded properties. ([Apple's reference page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput/1648766-supportedflashmodes) lacks Swift version of such properties. Hope Apple's review team would not take this as using private APIs, but not confirmed.

Comment: Apple has confirmed the mistake and use of `__xx` API instead. See here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86810

Comment: @ShaiBen-Tovim, thanks for the nice link. Happy to see that Apple's engineer has confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Apple camera dev team confirms the Swift version of the API was inadvertently left out of Xcode 9 release.
Until fixed have to use `__supportedFlashModes`

See here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86810
BTW some other AVFoundation APIs also affected.